# What's the rectangular form of this equation?

Tags: calculus

Resolve and express the solution of this equation in rectangular form:
$$ z^2 + 2\bar{z} -1=0 $$

I made this solution, but I'm not sure:

z can be expressed as (x+yi), so:

$$z=(x+yi)$$
$$\bar{z}=(x-yi)$$

$$=> (x-yi)^2 +2(x-yi)-1=0$$
$$ = x^2-y^2+2xyi = 1-2x+2yi$$

If I compare both real and imaginary parts:

$$2xyi=2yi$$
$$=>x=2yi/2yi=1$$

And accordingly...
$$x^2-y^2=1-2x$$
$$=>1-y^2 =1-2$$
$$=>y^2=2$$
$$=>y = \sqrt{2}$$
Then:

$$z=1+i\sqrt{2} $$
$$\bar{z}=1-i\sqrt{2}$$

Is that the correct answer? Wolfram Alpha tells me that this is the correct answer, but I don't know what does it mean.

Comment: You overlooked something when you deduced $x = 1$. In fact, there are two more solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $z=1+i\sqrt 2$ is a correct solution, but there are other solutions. It may have up to 4 solutions.

(1) from $y^2=2$, we have $y=\pm\sqrt 2$

(2) from $i\cdot 2xy = i\cdot 2y$ we have $x=1$ and $y=0$

$$i\cdot 2xy = i\cdot 2y$$
$$i\cdot 2xy - i\cdot 2y=0$$
$$i\cdot 2\cdot y\cdot (x-1) = 0$$
we have two solutions,  $x=1$ and $y=0$

So, for $y=0$, we need to solve: $$x^2+2x-1=0$$

The 4 solutions are $1+i\sqrt2$, $1-i\sqrt2$, $-1+\sqrt2$, $-1-\sqrt2$.

Comment: Can you explain me with more details the second step? This is exactly what I'm looking for. 
Also, can I say that z and ¬z, and the two solutions you gave me are the four total solutions?

Comment: I will add the details